# Is NSUserName() not working in xcode6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

NSUserName() doesn't seem to be working for me in Xcode 6 while developing iOS apps.
I was using it to get the desktop directory to save a core data seed to my desktop during development.

```
NSString* deskStorePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Desktop/newMySQL.CDBStore", NSUserName()];
```

I had to change my code to:

```
 #define USER_NAME @"myusername"
 NSString* deskStorePath02 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Desktop/newMySQL.CDBStore", USER_NAME];
```

Now NSUserName() returns nothing in Xcode 6, but had worked fine in Xcode 5.

```
NSString* myname = NSUserName();
NSString* myfullname = NSFullUserName();
NSLog(@"name : %@ - %@",myname,myfullname);
```

Is it a bug?
Do I need to import a library now?
Or is there an alternative to get the current OSX username during app development?

edit: (This is the method I'm using to save the core data seed store to desktop which I then add to my dev environment)

```
- (void) saveSeedToDesktop
{
    [self testNSUser];
    NSString* myDBName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.sqlite",CD_FILE_NAME];
    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent : myDBName];
    NSString* deskStorePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Desktop/newMySQL.CDBStore", USER_NAME];
    NSError*error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:storePath toPath: deskStorePath error:&error]){
        NSLog(@"error with path : %@",error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Copied");
    }
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

This is a test class:

```
- (void) testNSUser {
    NSString* myname = NSUserName();
    NSString* myfullname = NSFullUserName();
    NSLog(@"name : %@ - %@",myname,myfullname);

    __unused NSString* deskStorePathTest01 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/this_is_my_name/Desktop/test.txt"]; //works
    __unused NSString* deskStorePathTest02 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Desktop/test.txt"];
    __unused NSString* deskStorePathTest03 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/~/Desktop/test.txt"];
    __unused NSString* deskStorePathTest04 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/~/Desktop/test.txt"];

    [self fileExistsTest:deskStorePathTest01];
    [self fileExistsTest:deskStorePathTest02];
    [self fileExistsTest:deskStorePathTest03];
    [self fileExistsTest:deskStorePathTest04];
}

- (void) fileExistsTest : (NSString*)storePath {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *pathForFile = storePath;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathForFile]){
        NSLog(@"exists : %@",storePath);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"doesnt exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you use `~/Desktop` ?

Comment: No longer working on my end either on Xcode 6 > (lldb) po NSUserName()
<object returned empty description>

Comment: What's this got to do with Xcode 6?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue with assets produced by running the app in the simulator. I realised that the app itself is stored below my home directory so I could access my username from that:

```
NSString *userName = NSUserName();

#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
if (userName.length == 0)
{
    NSArray *bundlePathComponents = [NSBundle.mainBundle.bundlePath pathComponents];

    if (bundlePathComponents.count >= 3
        && [bundlePathComponents[0] isEqualToString:@"/"]
        && [bundlePathComponents[1] isEqualToString:@"Users"])
    {
        userName = bundlePathComponents[2];
    }
}
#endif
```

Obviously for development only.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, on the device, anyway.  It does not seem to work on the simulator.

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    if(self)
    {
        //Custom initialization.
        NSString *u = NSUserName();

        NSLog(@"%@", u);
    }

    return self;
}
```

Output is:

```
2014-10-05 20:45:38.451 [my app business] mobile
```

If I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish here, though, I think the prescribed way of initializing the Core Data store with default data may be to programmatically add it.  At least, that's what I took away from the docs.  I'm pretty sure they say somewhere that you're not supposed to manipulate the Core Data store file outside of the API.

Comment: On device I get the output, but its the wrong output:
 2014-10-16 11:25:31.183 APPNAME[1287:324349] name : mobile - Mobile User